# Sort characters ascending then numbers ascending

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Is there an easy trick to change the sort order to "first character values ascending, then numeric values ascending" when selecting?

```
   SELECT mycol
     FROM mytable
 ORDER BY mycol
```

Result:

```
1C
8Q
9G
AR
BZ
IT
```

With DESC:

```
   SELECT mycol
     FROM mytable
 ORDER BY mycol DESC
```

Result:

```
IT
BZ
AR
9G
8Q
1C
```

Desired result:

```
AR
BZ
IT
1C
8Q
9G
```

Comment: What happens when you get to `'ZZ'`  (actually, think it would be `'99'`)?

Comment: Will your column only have 2 characters?

Comment: After ZZ all rows starting with numeric values should be listed, like: 1A, 1B,... and so on

Comment: @LuisCazares in the current challenge yes. i'm not sure if i will need this sort order in future for further columns with more characters.

Comment: This kind of logic can be quite confusing, so it is difficult to answer. Which one comes first: `11` or `2A`? (Because 11 is numerically larger than 2...)

Comment: @BartHofland 11 should come before 2A, because looking at the first character, 1 is smaller than 2.

Comment: Then I personally would use a variant of @TimBiegeleisen's answer. I will post it shortly.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions! I am already out of office till monday. Will try all solutions immediately when back at work. Also performance wise

Comment: I've tried all the solutions posted. All of them work. I've added another solution with using a COLLATION in the ORDER BY clause too. Just in case somebody needs it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution i figured out would be to use `COLLATE` for the `ORDER BY` clause, using an EBCDIC collation. Performancewise as fast as other solutions. Maybe easier to write, but somehow tricky to read without comments. An advantage would be, it is working for columns with more than 1 or 2 characters too.

```
SELECT mycol
     FROM mytable
 ORDER BY mycol COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC278_CP1_CS_AS
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try using the `ASCII` function here along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT mycol
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN LEFT(mycol, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    LEFT(mycol, 1),
    CASE WHEN RIGHT(mycol, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    RIGHT(mycol, 1);
```

[image]

### Demo

The logic here uses four levels of sorting, a pair for each of the two characters in `mycol`.  The `CASE` expressions put letters before numbers.  After this, we simply sort ascending by number or letter.

One other approach to this would be to treat your column as a base 36 number (10 digits plus 26 letters), and then just sort based on that number converted back to a base 10 decimal.  But, this might be uglier and more convoluted than the solution I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

This option will divide the column into 2 to separate digits and letters.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('1C'),('8Q'),('9G'),('AR'),('BZ'),('IT'))x(MyCol)
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(MyCol, 0, PATINDEX( '%[A-Z]%', MyCol)),
         SUBSTRING(MyCol, PATINDEX( '%[A-Z]%', MyCol), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
    ('1C'),
    ('8Q'),
    ('9G'),
    ('AR'),
    ('BZ'),
    ('IT'),
    ('11'),
    ('2A')
) AS tbl(col)
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
       , col
```

Output:

```
AR
BZ
IT
11
1C
2A
8Q
9G
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
( MyCol VARCHAR(3))

insert @mytable VALUES ('IT'),('BZ'),('AR'),('1C'),('8Q')

SELECT
     MyCol
FROM @mytable
ORDER BY PATINDEX('[0-9]%',MyCol),MyCol
```

Comment: This will only sort on the first numeric digit, so it will put '10A' directly before '1C'

Answer (score 0):

My variant on @TimBiegeleisen's and @SalmanA's answers:

```
SELECT mycol
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN mycol LIKE '[^0-9]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    mycol;
```

(I don't know if indexes on columns in the ORDER BY clause can affect performance, but to be sure I would avoid function calls.)

Edit: Well, actually it's practically the same answer as @SalmanA's one...